# iPhone application accessing data values from different classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have 4 classes i.e views in my application. Class A, having variable a and b.

After clicking on button which is on view A of class A it leads to class B, which is table view controller.  Then class B leads to class C. then class C leads to class D.

Now i want to access values of a and b of class A into class D. I tried it with NSNotification but not succeeded.

Please suggest.

I tried with NSNotification:

i tried with NSNotification like Class A---

```
-(IBAction) selectButton:(id) sender{



NSString * a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Manjinder singh"];
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:a forKey:@"1"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sendMessage" object:self userInfo:dict];

}
```

Then Class D----

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sendMessage:) name:@"sendMessage" object:nil];
}
return self;
}




-(void)sendMessage:(NSNotification *)notification{


A *dil=[[A alloc] init];
nslog(@"dil.a");




NSLog(@"USERINFO:MyUserInfo (its a dictionary):%@",[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"1"]);
```

}

This is the rendom try but basically i want to show variable a and b of class A into class D.

Update:------------
    MyCoolViewController.h// a class where data send from

```
@protocol MyCoolViewDelegate;

@interface MyCoolViewController : UIViewController  {


id <MyCoolViewDelegate> delegate;//
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;//


@end
@protocol MyCoolViewDelegate <NSObject>//

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string;
@end

MyCoolViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad{

[delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"];
}




firstViewController.m  //a class where data sent
-(void)viewDidLoad{

MyCoolViewController *myViewControllerPointer=[[MyCoolViewController alloc] init];
myViewControllerPointer.delegate = self;//
}

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
//displays the string as console output
NSLog(@"plzzzzzz show data",string);
}
```

value of string is not passed to this class because it is not showing in NSLog output.
UPDATED 2---

```
MyCoolViewController.m

#import “MyCoolViewController.h”
#import "firstViewController.h"


@implementation MyCoolViewController
@synthesize label1,sttr; 



@synthesize delegate;//







-(IBAction) selectButton:(id) sender{



if (curri==nil) {

     curri=[[CurrancyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];



    [self.navigationController pushViewController:curri animated:YES];
}

      curri=nil;

  //CHECK ThIS  [curri release];
}






- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"];






self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"]];




[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give more context about what specifically you are trying to achieve?  It sounds like you want to pass data between several `UIViewController`s.  Here is how to set up a delegate for one of your view controllers:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MyCoolViewControllerDelegate;
@interface MyCoolViewController : UIViewController {
    id <MyCoolViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end

@protocol MyCoolViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string;

@end
```

Then you will should synthesize the delegate

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

and then when you want to pass data to, lets say a parent view, call this function:

`[delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"];`

In the other view controller, wherever you instantiated the instance of this UIViewController, you need to set that self as the delegate;

`myViewControllerPointer.delegate = self;`

and then implement the delegate function in the parent view controller.

```
 -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
   //displays the string as console output
   NSLog(string);
}
```

The fact that you need communicate between views like this could possibly mean that there is a more efficient means of structuring your app.  Can't say for sure without more info.

Try and use this template to add a delegate to your own app.

Comment: Hello  James Thanks for your time.Actually i want to pass data from say MyCoolViewController to AnotherClassController. I have a confusion. Where shall i call [delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"];?  and where and how call myViewControllerPointer.delegate=self;?  Hope you reply to this. Sorry about it im beggener.

Comment: I didnot accept you answer despite of the fact that i really apprciate it coz i have this confusion n as soon as solved i will accept it. thanks

Comment: And the declaration of this protocol is in MyCoolViewController class from where i want to send data?

Comment: @harpreet Kaur you call [delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"]; from the .m file of MyCoolViewController, where you send data from.  you call myViewcontrollerPointer.delegate=self in whatever class/view controller you would like to act as the delegate for the first view controller, ie the view controller you want to pass data to.

Comment: Actually i am new that is why asking so many question hope that will be ok with you. Yes agree firstViewControlle is class to where i want to send data, and MyCoolViewController is class from where i send data. and our protocol is also defined in MyCoolViewController?. and -(void)sendStringToAnoterhView method is also in firstViewController. So there are just 2 classes contains all above code? Please confirm above

Comment: Thats correct.  You define the function in the protocol, call it from MyCoolViewController, and then implement it in firstViewController.

Comment: Give a 1 minute i will try it n let you know :-) this protocol is also defined in MyCoolViewController? there is no separate class for protocol?

Comment: say my receiving class is firstViewController. so in viewDidLoad method of firstViewController i am using it as MyCoolViewController *myViewcontrollerPointer=[[MyCoolVoewController alloc]init]; myViewcontrollerPointer.delegate=self; and implementing method  -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
   
   NSLog(string);
}       But it is not getting called

Comment: But James it is not getting called. i am not getting nslog output

Comment: I can't tell you what you did wrong without seeing your code.  Update your question to include current code.  But to be sure, you are calling [delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"]; from MyCoolViewController?

Comment: I think problem is making instance of MyViewController i.e. myViewControllerPointer.delegare=self;

Comment: Yes i am  calling [delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"this is a string"];in MyCoolViewController class. Please check my reply here.  within 3  minutes i am updating my question with this code. and suggest me.

Comment: Please post the entirety of MyCoolViewController.m.  Did you synthesize delegate?

Comment: Yes i synthesis it. I think  -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
   //displays the string as console output
   NSLog(string);
} in firstViewController is not get called? how can i  call i in viewDidLoad? It is not possible to paste all class ..its too bid

Comment: When i call [self sendAStringToAnotherView:string];
 in viewDidLoad method of firstViewController it says undeclared variable "string";

Comment: Just get rid of all functions that don't pertain to the question.  I need to see more to be able to help you.  Also, don't forget to call [super viewDidLoad]; in your viewDidLoad methods.

Comment: Thats because you haven't defined a variable called string in firstViewController.  Add this line: NSString *string = @"test"; before [self sendAStringToAnotherView:string];

Comment: one sec i m posting whole class

Comment: i have posted it plz check. iremoved dealloc method which are unnecceory

Comment: code you posted looks fine.  try calling the delegate from that -(IBAction) selectButton:(id) sender method, instead of showing that new view.  but it should be working.

Comment: look, I've given you absolutely everything you need to make this work.  I'm willing to continue helping you if you first accept my answer.

Comment: Yes i agree. Thanku so much for your help. i have accepted it. n yes am trying to put this code into method instead of viewDidLoad. But value of string shows null.

Comment: Sorry, lost power for a while there.  Thanks for accepting.  So firstViewController is firing the method, but the console readout says the string in nil?

Comment: Yes i think we are near our result. now firstViewController is firing. but console is nil

Comment: in firstViewController viewDidLoad { MyCoolViewController *myViewControllerPointer=[[MyCoolViewController alloc] init];
    myViewControllerPointer.delegate = self;//
   
    NSString *a=myViewControllerPointer.string ;
    NSLog(@"dildil dil%@",a);} a is null

Comment: have u got msn id. just give me 10 minutes we can then quickly solve it if possible.

Comment: James you told me to initilise string with test as NSString *string = @"test";
    
    [self sendAStringToAnotherView:string];
    
now in -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
    //displays the string as console output
    //NSLog(string);
    NSLog(@"lolo%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string]);

    
   
    

} it shows test not values returned by myCoolViewController class

Answer (score 2):

You could use delegation here

D would become the delegate of A, and when you click the button, A sends a message to D with the variables as arguments and D responds by performing a method.

Comment: Yes can you please let me know how? i would be really thankful to you. i am stuck with it for 2 days

Comment: I was trying to access a from D as A *objecta=[[A alloc]init]nslog( objecta.a); but it shows null

Comment: *objecta=[[A alloc]init];nslog( objecta.a); --> this would create an additional instance of the A class, that would probably be empty (or just initialized to its default values). You need to access the original instance instead. To do that, you need to hold a valid reference to that instance, or use delegation (which still requires having a reference), or use notifications (overkill, imho).

Comment: Yes how can i hold a valid reference of class A in D. or use delegating. Plz suggest

Comment: Please give me simple way to access variables of A in D. i really appriciate it

Comment: @Mahir E Yes i have seen and appreciate that. But i have a confusion. I have classes say A and D. In which class this protocol has defined? and where are other classes calling?

Comment: @Mehir E. i followed exactly what James told me i have shown the actual code into my question update. now in my receiver class i have used method with argument. when i call that method it shows error on argument saying it is undeclared why?

Comment: did you conform to the protocol?

You have to write <MyCoolViewDelegate> in the header file of the receiver class

Comment: @Mehir E yes i did. i am able to send string but not string object. i have string object like label.text=townName; NSLog(@"%@",townName);//it prints value. when i send townName in the sending method it shows null value